# Get populated data from Mongoose to the client

Tags: javascript, mongodb, mongoose, graphql, apollo

On the server, I am populating user-data and when I am printing it to the console everything is working fine but I am not able to access the data on the client or even on `Playground` of `GraphQL`.

This is my Schema

```
const { model, Schema } = require("mongoose");

const postSchema = new Schema({
    body: String,
    user: {
        type: Schema.Types.ObjectId,
        ref: "User",
    },
});

module.exports = model("Post", postSchema);
```

```
const userSchema = new Schema({
    username: String,
});

module.exports = model("User", userSchema);
```

```
const { gql } = require("apollo-server");

module.exports = gql`
    type Post {
        id: ID!
        body: String!
        user: [User]!
    }
    type User {
        id: ID!
        username: String!
    }
    type Query {
        getPosts: [Post]!
        getPost(postId: ID!): Post!
    }
`;
```

```
Query: {
        async getPosts() {
            try {
                const posts = await Post.find()
                    .populate("user");

                console.log("posts: ", posts[0]);
// This works and returns the populated user with the username

                return posts;
            } catch (err) {
                throw new Error(err);
            }
        },
}
```

But on the client or even in Playground, I can't access the populated data.

```
query getPosts {
  getPosts{
    body
    user {
       username
    }
  }
}
```

My question is how to access the data from the client.

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0):

you are using this feature in the wrong way you should defined a Object in your resolvers with your model name and that object should contain a method that send the realated user by the parant value.

here is a full document from apollo server docs for [how to use this feature](https://www.apollographql.com/docs/apollo-server/data/resolvers/#resolver-chains)

Comment: I didn't quite understand you. Do you mean the feature with populate or resolver? I must add that everything works except that I don't get data to the client when I populate(). But I can access body from the client and Playground..

Comment: there is no need to populate.

Comment: cause only you can populate once or twice or ... you dont know how much depth user wants to go this is the graph part.

Comment: for impelemting this part you need to update your resolvers. you should return just the object without populating using mongoose then in your resovers you have to add a object with name of your model type in schema. after that you have to implement a method on it that returns the wanted document based on parent values. check the link i gave you for better information and if it didnt help you again i recommend watch a youtube video on the topic

Answer (score 0):

use `lean()` like this :

```
 const posts = await Post.find().populate("user").lean();
```

Comment: after I tried .lean() on Playground it says: 

"errors": [{ "message": "Cannot return null for non-nullable field Post.user.",

Comment: Can you run mongoose on playground??